# ProblemDetails: Change in Instance Handling?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on upgrading an MVC application from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 3.1.

So far so good with actual behavior of the application, but an existing test condition is failing because an error payload used to contain "instance: null" but now no longer does.

Where we're using `ProblemDetails`, we weren't setting `Instance` explicitly, which is why it was null. After upgrading to ASP.NET Core 3.1, instance isn't there in the error payload.

I've looked through breaking changes and searched for anyone else having this issue. Is this a known issue?

I'm expecting we'll want to update our test conditions, but I'm also trying to figure out whether this was a known/breaking change documented anywhere in the ASP.NET Core upgrade pathway.

Comment: What's the problem? How to deal with the "instance : null" ?

Comment: The _problem_ is just that an existing test condition started failing.

I'd just like to be able to point to a reference to the apparent change in behavior. I haven't found documentation of it. It would be easier to justify changing the test condition if I knew for sure that this was a .NET Core upgrade side effect.

Comment: Can you share some piece of code and repro steps to describe the issue detailly?